# append bytes to string in java

Tags: java, string, append

I have to deal with ascii structured file, I need to put these two constant bytes to the end of every line so that I can respect the file structure that was gave me:

```
private final static int ENDRECORD = 0x0d;
private final static int ENDLINE = 0x0a;
```

I don't know if it's the classic "\n", is there a way I can put these two variables at the end of a string?
Like:

> String line = line + ENDRECORD + ENDLINE; //I now this is wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're close.  It's `'\r'` and `'\n'`.

```
System.out.println((int) '\r');
System.out.println((int) '\n');
```

Output:

```
13
10
```

which is `0x0d` and `0x0a`, respectively.  Use `char`s:

```
private final static char ENDRECORD = '\r';
private final static char ENDLINE = '\n';
```

and

```
String line = line + ENDRECORD + ENDLINE;
```

Additionally, you can use `StringBuilder` for efficiency instead of concatenation.  It's not necessary to get this to work, but it's standard to use it for building strings instead of concatenation with `+`.

Comment: It would be no more efficient to use StringBuilder for the code we've seen so far. StringBuilder is great for avoiding *repeated* concatenation, but for a *single* (multi-value) concatenation operation as we've got here, it's pointless.

Answer (score 1):

Just change your constants to be strings instead:

```
private final static String ENDRECORD = "\r";
private final static String ENDLINE = "\n";
```

Then your existing concatenation should be fine.

`char` would be fine too:

```
private final static char ENDRECORD = '\r'; // Or (char) 0x0d
private final static char ENDLINE = '\n';   // Or (char) 0x0a
```

You should think of characters *as characters* rather than either bytes or integer values. It'll make your text handling a lot simpler.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the datatype to `char`.

```
String myFullLine = line + (char)ENDRECORD + (char)ENDLINE;
```

If your are planning on doing this for more than one line I recommed using a `StringBuilder`.

Comment: That will still give the wrong answer, as it will be appending the textual representation of integers. And unless there *is* a loop involved, there's no point using a StringBuilder here. A single concatenation operation is fine.

Comment: Now with the edit, it will work - but the StringBuilder part is still a complete red herring.

Comment: Yea, saw my mistake. The reason I am putting a StringBuilder is because I assume that there will be more than on line in the end and at that point it would be more efficient than string concatenation.

Comment: It's not clear from the post that any further concatenation *is* required - and certainly your answer doesn't differentiate between the advice of using a StringBuilder and the "fix the data types" part which is actually important.

Comment: Fine, I guess I went a bit off topic. Fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

You will want the values to be characters instead of integers.

So, you can do it like so:

```
private static final char ENDRECORD = (char)0x0d;
private static final char ENDLINE = (char)0x0a;
...
line = line + ENDRECORD + ENDLINE;
```

I'm going to assume you have more than a single record, so a better way would be to create a loop for each record and use a `StringBuilder`:

```
StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder(4096);
for (final String record: records) {
  buffer.setLength(0);
  buffer.append(record).append(ENDRECORD).append(ENDLINE);
  String line = buffer.toString();
  ...
}
```

If all you're going to do the the record is to output it, then there's no need to put it in a `StringBuilder`; just write it to your Stream or Writer:

```
OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("records.dat");
for (final String record: records) {
   out.write(record.getBytes());
   out.write(ENDRECORD);
   out.write(ENDLINE);
}
```

Comment: Using an OutputStream directly for text data isn't a good idea; wrap it in an OutputStreamWriter. (Or use FileWriter, but I dislike that as you can't specify the encoding.)

Comment: If this is a data record format, you likely don't want language character conversion.

Comment: He's dealing with *strings*. There will *absolutely* be a text to binary conversion going on, whatever else happens. There's no other way of starting off with a String in memory and getting a file on disk (which is inherently binary data). Your current code just uses the platform-default encoding, which is almost *always* the wrong approach IMO.

Comment: If a specific encoding is needed, one can always use `getBytes(encoding)`.

Comment: Yes, but why not just do that via `OutputStreamWriter`? Aside from anything else, your code currently assumes that `ENDRECORD` and `ENDLINE` are already in an appropriate encoding - not a good idea. (Imagine if we want UTF-16.) Mostly this is a matter of principle: if you want to write out text, use a `Writer`.

Comment: Well, he does state "ascii" in the question, so I think if anything you'd want `US-ASCII` as the encoding, which overlaps UTF-8 for the lowest 7 bits.

Comment: Agreed, but the point is you still need to consider it - contrary to your claim of "you likely don't want language character conversion". It would be very easy to copy the code you've written in a different context, specify UTF-16 just for the `getBytes()`, but forget the rest. Using a `Writer` (e.g. OutputStreamWriter) is simply a better approach.